# hp g7 screen dark on login need corrective action

Tags: boot, fedora, login

I have a HP g7 that's running Fedora 17 which has a dark unlit screen on login. I need the exact keystrokes I need to type in order to sign in, so that I don't need to use a flash light to see the sign in menu.

Comment: Does the screen light up after you are logged in?